# Lemma 23.1 of Munkres’ Topology

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

> If $Y$ is a subspace of $X$, a separation of $Y$ is a pair of disjoint nonempty sets $A$ and $B$ whose union is $Y$, neither of which contains a limit point of the other. The space $Y$ is connected if there exists no separation of $Y$.

Lemma 23.1 statement is vague, IMO.  [Munkres Lemma 23.1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2927079/861687). Rephrasing it

> $Y$ is connected(usual definition) $\iff$ $\nexists$ separation of $Y$. Property of separation is given in lemma 23.1.

Munkres used two different notion of separation. We can rephrase lemma 23.1 by showing two notion of separation of $Y$ are equivalent.

> $A,B\in \mathcal{T}_{Y}$, $A,B\neq \emptyset$, $A\cap B=\emptyset$ and $A\cup B=Y$ $\iff$ $A,B\neq \emptyset$, $A\cap B=\emptyset$, $A\cup B=Y$, $\overline{A}\cap B=\emptyset$ (or equivalently $A’\cap B=\emptyset$) and $A\cap \overline{B}=\emptyset$ (or equivalently $A\cap B’=\emptyset$). In other word, Assume $A,B\neq \emptyset$, $A\cap B=\emptyset$ and $A\cup B=Y$. $A,B\in \mathcal{T}_Y$ $\iff$ $\overline{A} \cap B=\emptyset$ and $A\cap \overline{B}=\emptyset$.

**Is my interpretation correct?**

Comment: Yes it is………..,

Comment: please make it a separate self-contained question.

Comment: A few lines or no, asking new questions in the comments to an old question is a poor use of the site, guaranteeing that no-one but the OP (you) and those who have made comments will ever see the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use that $Y=A \cup B$ separated, then $A \cap \overline{B}=\emptyset$ and so $A \subseteq Y\setminus \overline{B}$. It follows that $A$ is open in $Y$ (as the complement of $\overline{B}$). Symmetrically $B$ is open in $Y$ as well (as the complement of $\overline{A}$). So a separation via "separated sets" is the same as a separation by disjoint open sets and vice versa.

So it doesn't matter which separation we use in the definition of (dis)connectedness.